# How launchd StartInterval behaves after long sleep?

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, launchd, plist

I have a 21,600secs (4hours) job using launchd.plist.  I have 2 mac, main and sub.  With main mac, my plist works fine.  But with sub mac, which is wakes up 3~4 times per week, my plist does not seems to run properly.

Apple's man page for launchd.plist describes:

> If the system is asleep, the job will
>        be started the next time the computer wakes up.  If multiple intervals transpire before the computer is
>        woken, those events will be coalesced into one event upon wake from sleep.

But if sleep time is longer than 86,400secs (1day), I can't find out how the counter works.

Does anyone know how startinterval works after over a day?

Comment: Hi, did you find an answer for this? I have the same question.

Comment: @becko No. I don't have any answer for this old question...